# Iterating through a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tuples

Iterating through a list of tuples
[('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f',6)]

attempting to get the matching pair as output

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

here is what I have so far:

```
data = [('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f',6)]
new_list = []
vowels = 'aeiou'
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxw'
consonants = list(consonants)
vowels = list(vowels)
for idx, (a,b) in enumerate(data):
    if (a) in vowels or (a) in consonants and (b) % 3 == 0:
        new_list.append(idx)
print tuple(new_list)
```

This where I am getting stuck

Comment: Sorry I can't quite understand your question. What does [(0,4), (1,2), (3,4)] mean? The numbers of item (3,4) adds up to 5 which does not seem to be a multiple of 3.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, it is suppose to be (3,6)

Comment: I think your results should have either `(5,3)` or `(3,5)` but not `(3,4)`

Comment: You need 2 loops. For each element in list, iterate thru list to find all its matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it, which you can expand on later:

```
nums = [('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f',6)]
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
results = []
for k,v in enumerate(nums):
    for i,j in enumerate(nums[:]):
        if v == j:
            continue
        if v[0] in vowels and j[0] in vowels:
            if (v[1]+j[1]) % 3 == 0:
                if (i,k) not in results:
                    results.append((k,i))
        if v[0] not in vowels and j[0] not in vowels:
            if (v[1]+j[1]) % 3 == 0:
                if (k,i) not in results:
                    results.append((i,k))
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f',6)]
new_list = []
vowels = 'aeiou'
for idx,(a,b) in enumerate(data):
     for _idx,(_a,_b) in enumerate( data[idx+1:]):
           if bool(a in vowels)==bool(_a in vowels) and(b+_b)%3==0:
               new_list.append((idx,_idx+idx+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [('a', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f',6)] 
c = np.asarray([[int(e[0] in 'aeiou'), e[1]] for e in a])
e = (c[:,None] + c) % 3
f = np.asarray(np.where((e[...,0]%2==0) & (e[...,1]==0))).T.tolist()
print set([tuple(sorted(i)) for i in f if i[0]!=i[1]])

set([(1L, 2L), (3L, 5L), (0L, 4L)])
```